# Converting Java Program into C++

Tags: java, c++

I have converted this code from `java` to `C++` but i am unable to convert `boolean` (variable) and its related code. Kindly help and tell me if i can use any header along with it.

```
boolean[][] bombs = new boolean[M+2][N+2];
  for (int i = 1; i <= M; i++){
     for (int j = 1; j <= N; j++){
        bombs[i][j] = (Math.random() < p);
    }
}
  for (int i = 1; i <= M; i++) {
     for (int j = 1; j <= N; j++){
        if (bombs[i][j]) cout<<"* ";
        else             cout<<". ";
    }
     cout<<endl;
  }
  int[][] sol = new int[M+2][N+2];
  for (int i = 1; i <= M; i++)
     for (int j = 1; j <= N; j++)
        for (int ii = i - 1; ii <= i + 1; ii++)
           for (int jj = j - 1; jj <= j + 1; jj++)
              if (bombs[ii][jj]) sol[i][j]++;

  cout<<endl;

  for (int i = 1; i <= M; i++) {
     for (int j = 1; j <= N; j++)
        if (bombs[i][j]) cout<<"* ";
        else             cout<<sol[i][j] + " ";
     cout<<endl;
  }
```

Comment: use std::vector or static arrays. Your code does not compile. And in C++ boolean is bool.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  Unless it's homework it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: i am unable to complete it. its my university final project

Answer (score 2):

I won't write code for you (smells like homework), and won't even begin to comment on those loops.

A few problems:

1. `boolean` is spelled `bool` in c++
2. If you want to have variable length arrays you must use either `std::vector`, or you can use raw pointers to get array syntax (but then don't forget to delete them
3. As an aside, `T[] foo` is not correct in c++.  If you wanted a static array it'd be `T foo[]`

Also, just because you *can* write very dense c++ code without braces or spaces between operators does not mean you *should*.

Can vs. should is a very important part of good c++ - a lot more so than many other, more restrictive languages (e.g. Java). `</soapbox>`

Comment: +1 for identifying it as homework but still helping him understanding how he can make it by his own efforts...

Answer (score 0):

You should use [bool](http://www.functionx.com/cpp/keywords/bool.htm) data type. You don't need to use any header file for this.

Comment: He _should_ be using header-files, namely `vector` or related.

Comment: Oh, I meant specifically to `bool`. Yes, he needs the other ones.